# Google Cloud Scheduler trigger last day of month

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I want to create a trigger in Google Cloud Scheduler that runs at 9am on the 25th **and** the last day of each month (depending of the month that would be 28, 30, or 31th).

I assumed somethink like this might work, but GCP does not understand the L-syntax:
`0 9 25,L * *`

Any (elegant) ideas how to do it without having multiple triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trigger, with minimized overhead calls:

`0 0 25,28-31 * *`

Then, inside the function:

```
IF is25() OR islastDayOfMonthHelper()
  work
ELSE 
  return
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention two alternative options I see for the end of month part of the question.

1. Simply run the function just past midnight to the 1st of each month. Depending on your use case this may be good enough.
2. Reschedule the function each month to the specific date which will be the last day of the next month.